# How to load pdf url from google drive in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, google-drive-api

I am trying to load pdf from google drive using **LazyPDFDocument**. Installed **LazyPDFDocument** for annotate, modify, etc. Right now i can able to load pdf from local [From inside xcode project], edit and save. Here is the code i tried so far:

```
 let pdfs = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "pdf", inDirectory: nil)

    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfs.first!))

    let filePath = pdfs.first

    let document = LazyPDFDocument(filePath: filePath, password: phrase)

    if document != nil {

        let lazyPDFViewController = LazyPDFViewController(lazyPDFDocument: document)

        lazyPDFViewController?.delegate = self

        let file = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: (document?.filePath)!, contents: data, attributes: nil)

        lazyPDFViewController?.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

        lazyPDFViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        self.present(lazyPDFViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

My question is to load pdf from **google drive** using **LazyPDFViewController**?

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: If you able download to PDF from drive then you can.

Comment: @MathiArasan yes i can get url from google drive but can't able to load url in uiview.

Comment: From your code, this `LazyPDFViewController` looks like accept only `LazyPDFDocument(filePath: filePath, password: phrase)` like this. So, you should download drive file to your app path/location (temp or whatever) then use this method.

Comment: @MathiArasan how to save pdf url inside app. If url is from bundle then i can load pdf inside view. In case of url from google drive can't able to load

Comment: I don't have exact code what you expect, I assume you are using `AlamoFire` so surely there is an option to download a file from the web. search and download and save it to your app directory.